# Spring data with AWS ElastiCache

Tags: amazon-web-services, java-8, spring-data, amazon-elasticache

Can we use `@Repository` interface with `AWS ElastiCache`?

I can probably always have `spring-data-redis` (assuming the underlying Cache is Redis) and use `@Repository` but that will not be using the `ElastiCache` APIs, which also means I'll lose the abstraction that the ElastiCache API will provide otherwise from the underlying data store...

Answer (score 0):

AWS ElastiCache APIs don't expose any abstraction for underlying service Provider.

> Amazon ElastiCache is a web service that makes it easier to set up, operate, and scale a distributed cache in the cloud.